# Why would I want to use Android Studio's "Expand Boolean" Intention?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Android Studio is, apart from other things, a fairly fancy Java IDE, and it has a bunch of built-in language specific edit features that can perform various code transformations.  One of these that surprised me is "Expand Boolean", and its partner "Expand Boolean to multiple ifs".  The documentation says that the first will transform this:

```
public class X {
  boolean f(boolean a) {
    return a;
  }
}
```

into this:

```
public class X {
  boolean f(boolean a) {
    if(a) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

My question is why you might want to?  Is there a performance advantage to be had in Java?  The original version seems to be superior in terms of clarity and conciseness.

Comment: FWIW - Android Studio is a fork of IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: I don't know either, it kind of surprises me that there would be a function that produces **more** code, without adding anything to the clarity.. Pretty strange.

Comment: IntelliJ is very Intelligent. It knows `boolean f(boolean a) {return a;}` simply coding mistake,  As it's doing nothing. So It suggest that you might want to perform some action before returning the same argument value.

Comment: @DhavalPatel It's not necessarily a coding mistake.  That could be a legitimate implementation of the method.  The IDE has no way of knowing.

Comment: @Andrew Could you post a link to the documentation that you're referencing here?

Comment: The original code is odd, but could be reasonable (say `f` is required by an implemented interface) the expanded code is just plain weird.

Comment: @DougStevenson The documentation I asked about might be on-line somewhere, but I encountered it in the AndroidStudio configuration panel under Editor->Intentions->Boolean.  I asked here after being unable to find anything useful after a bit of googling, so I doubt that it is on-line as such.

Comment: @AndrewReilly Got it.  The answer given seems correct to me.  It's just a refactoring convenience.

Answer (score 2):

Intentions are not necessarily quick fixes, sometimes they are just warnings or available macros for micro-refactoring. 
The one in question doesn't assume any error with your code since this one also appears with

```
boolean f(boolean a, boolean b) {
    return b&&a;
}
```

What is trying to provide is a way to move from boolean expression to conditional alternative. Sometimes your condition becomes complex and doesn't fit into a single expression any more and you end up writing an if. So, instead of writing it by hand, it offers you to do so automatically. 
Note that, once you apply the intention, other intentions like `clean code` and `simplify` appear, and applying them will undo the expansion. And this time they appear as quick fixes, since now it's actually seeing a problem with your code.

In other words, this is just a macro useful as a first step for further changes and probably wasn't created to use it alone. 
**It doesn't actually suggest you to do the change, but just letting you know that it can be handled automatically if you intend to do it.**

On a side note, [the user documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/intention-actions.html) reference this kind of intentions as suggestions, but I find that name misleading for the reasons I stated above.

Comment: Thanks.  That sounds entirely plausible.